# How to select a part from a list of text imported from the internet

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering, xml

I import a dataset from the internet like:

> data=Import["http://www.test.com", {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]

The dataset looks like this:

```
{"02 jan", "40,250", "40,400", "40,150", "40,590", "152.289"
.....
"27 jan", "39,900", "39,560", "39,130", "39,910", "265.867"
, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "ValueDown"}, {"-1,090"}]
, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "ValueDown"}, {"-2,68%"}]
, "28 jan", "39,730", "40,080", "39,270", "40,080", "207.516"
, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "ValueUp"}, {"+0,520"}]
, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "ValueUp"}, {"+1,31%"}]
, "29 jan", "40,030", "40,170", "39,890", "40,460", "189.669"
...
, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "ValueDown"}, {"-0,90%"}]
, XMLElement["span", {}, {"10 feb"}], XMLElement["a", {"shape" -> "rect", 
  "title" -> "Beleggen in vastgoed? Dit zijn de opties", 
  "href" -> "http://www.test.nl/text/493371/text.aspx", 
  "target" -> "_blank"}, {"text"}], XMLElement["span", {}, {"07 feb"}],
....
};
```

I used "....." to show that in real the dataset us much bigger. Now I want to select the left part until the string: XMLElement["span", {}, {"10 feb"}].

Who has a suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: `position = Position[data, XMLElement["span", {}, {"10 feb"}]]`; `data[[;; position - 1]]`

Comment: What is your desired outcome? `data/.XMLElement[__]:> Nothing` or each left-part match in a separate list?  Also a minimum working example would be useful.